# using Delegate and its selector

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, cocoa

I have a certain scenario where I am trying to accomplish more generic approach of using delegate and calling a selector based on what selector is being set.

For example below is the code:

```
@protocol HttpRequestDelegate
@optional


- (void)testDrive:(NSData*)dataembedd;

@end


- (id)init {

    self = [super init]; 

    if (self) {

        //Initialize it here.
        self.HttpRequestdelegate = self;
    }

    return self;
}

HttpRequest *apiCaller = [[HttpRequest alloc] init];
        NSLog(@"%@",apiCaller.HttpRequestdelegate);
        [WLCC_ApiCaller executeAsync:apiCaller.HttpRequestdelegate :@selector(testDrive:) :[NSURL URLWithString:updateUrl] :wlcc_Get];
```

However at executeAsync call I am trying to call the selector which is test drive like:

```
[delegate performSelector:@selector(selector) withObject:responseData];
```

but it gives me an error of unknown selector, however when I notice the reference of the delegate its the same when initialized.

I am trying to utilize delegate perform selector in different class, is there anything else besides that I need to do here?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try ***[delegate performSelector:selector withObject:responseData];***?

Comment: @EmptyStack I tried that and I am getting -[HttpRequest testDrive:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7c26520'error.

Comment: How are you declaring `HttpRequestdelegate`? What is `self.HttpRequestdelegate`?

Comment: I think the *init* method is in the class *HttpRequest*. You are setting `self.HttpRequestdelegate = self;`. This is wrong. I think you are trying to accomplish something different. I am not sure about that. Please explain a bit more about what you are trying to do.

Comment: @EmptyStack so basically I have a Httprequest class which have a class method. In that class method let say service1 makes a web-service call which calls "api-caller" class which also have a class method. In that, I send a generic delegate with a dedicated selector, so once the nsurlconnection is completed, it call that selector of hence a delegate. That is what I am trying to achieve here. Does this makes sense?

Comment: Why doesn't the `WLCC_ApiCaller executeAsync:` method have names for any of the arguments? That's really hard to read.

Comment: @rmaddy this is my executeAsync arguements: + (void)executeAsync:(id)delegate:(SEL)selector:(NSURL*)request:(NSString*)httpMethod;

Comment: @kforkarim Right. There is nothing before any of the colons (except the 1st one). As it stands now, the method name is `executeAsync::::`. That's not very self-documenting.

Answer (score 0):

Define your protocol like this:

```
@protocol HttpRequestDelegate <NSObject>
```

There is an `NSObject` class and an `NSObject` protocol. All of your protocols should conform to the `NSObject` protocol. This gives you methods like `respondsToSelector:` and others.

Comment: @maddy, I am trying this: if ([delegate respondsToSelector:selector]) {
                
                [delegate performSelector:@selector(selector) withObject:responseData];
                
            } after your suggestion and its bypassing that if statement. and if I remove such if statement it crashes with same unrecognized error

Comment: What is `selector`? You don't show enough code to be sure what arguments you need. Either way, what you pass to `respondsToSelector:` and `performSelector:` need to be the same. In your comment they are different.

Comment: Yes you are right it should be performSelector:selector not @selector btw this is a modification I have conducted and got the delegate working ..                                                                HttpRequest *apiCaller = [[HttpRequest alloc] init];
[apiCaller setHttpRequestdelegate:[NSObjectAppDelegate class]];

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it should be; as what it seems that you're implementing the functions in other and try to call from that place which not inherited the delegate and, possible miss that particular function implementation.

Normally, the delegate pattern is used so we can implement the function according to our need (or can say provide callback) but that class must conform that delegate.Have you checked for it?

Please elaborate more about your implementation as I think so many info are behind the curtains like : WLCC_ApiCaller executeAsync,etc.

Comment: Mohit, in my case as since not a particular class is setting the delegate, hence I am setting the delegate with class type as setDelegate:[Class name]; That worked for me. I had seen same contents on one of the examples somewhere.